# PHP Form redirects to blank screen after hitting submit

Tags: php, html

I feel like this is a stupid question to ask with a really simple answer, I have tried looking at the other questions related to this topic but i dont really get it from those.

I have a simple HTML and PHP contact form, it is redirecting to a blank page.

I get that i will probably need a "header" part in there somewhere, but then how would the status messages from the PHP show up in the browser if it redirects back to the previous page?

I have tried adding in the redirect and that works, but no messages show up saying that it is successful.

So far I haven't even verified that the email function is working, because I am trying to sort this part out.

**HTML CODE**

```
<div class="col-lg-8 mt-5 mt-lg-0" data-aos="fade-left">
            <h2>Simple PHP Contact Form</h2>
            <div class="contactFrm">
              <?php if(!empty($statusMsg)){ ?>
              <p class="statusMsg <?php echo !empty($msgClass)?$msgClass:''; ?>">
                <?php echo $statusMsg; ?>
              </p>
              <?php } ?>
              <form action="forms/contact.php" method="post">
                <h4>Name</h4>
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" required="">
                <h4>Email </h4>
                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email@example.com" required="">
                <h4>Subject</h4>
                <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Write subject" required="">
                <h4>Message</h4>
                <textarea name="message" placeholder="Write your message here" required=""> </textarea>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
                <div class="clear"> </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
```

**PHP CODE**

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
set_error_handler("var_dump");
$statusMsg = '';
$msgClass = '';
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    // Get the submitted form data
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    
    // Check whether submitted data is not empty
    if(!empty($email) && !empty($name) && !empty($subject) && !empty($message)){
        
        if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false){
            $statusMsg = 'Please enter your valid email.';
            $msgClass = 'errordiv';
        }else{
            // Recipient email
            $toEmail = '985thenquiries@protonmail.com';
            $emailSubject = 'Contact Request Submitted by '.$name;
            $htmlContent = '<h2>Contact Request Submitted</h2>
                <h4>Name</h4><p>'.$name.'</p>
                <h4>Email</h4><p>'.$email.'</p>
                <h4>Subject</h4><p>'.$subject.'</p>
                <h4>Message</h4><p>'.$message.'</p>';

            print("I worked?");
            
            // Set content-type header for sending HTML email
            $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
            
            // Additional headers
            $headers .= 'From: '.$name.'<'.$email.'>'. "\r\n";
            
            // Send email
            if(mail($toEmail,$emailSubject,$htmlContent,$headers)){
                $statusMsg = 'Your contact request has been submitted successfully !';
                $msgClass = 'succdiv';
                print("submission successful");
                print($name);
            }else{
                $statusMsg = 'Your contact request submission failed, please try again.';
                $msgClass = 'errordiv';
                print("sub brok");
            }
        }
    }else{
        $statusMsg = 'Please fill all the fields.';
        $msgClass = 'errordiv';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: It is working fine without any errors, check whether you put contact.php in correct location i.e. it should be in forms folder as per your action attribute.

Comment: `Check whether submitted data is not empty` if empty you are NOT printing the statuses. If empty please print `$statusMsg` and see